# Hiding a Div for a Group Called New Joinees?

Tags: html, css

I have the following Div which I have to hide for a particular group of users? I have two groups "New Joinees" and "Administrators". I want this div to be hidden for New Joinees and visible for Administrators.

How do I achieve that in HTML or CSS using if else statement?

```
<div class="tab-content-block">
<div class="home-subheading">'Functional Requirement Documents for Internal    
Users Only'</div>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li><a   
href="02_Business_System_Functionality/Non_Functional_Requirements">'Non   
Functional Requirements'</a></li>
<li><a href="02_Business_System_Functionality/Imaging">'Imaging'</a></li>
<li><a   
href="02_Business_System_Functionality/Confirmation_Management">
'Confirmation Management'</a></li>
<li><a   href="02_Business_System_Functionality/Requirement_Follow_Up">
'Requirement Follow Up'</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am using Deksicript and you can use the following but I am not sure how to use this

```
if (!user.groups['New Joinees']) {
[put statements here]
}
```

"!" is the Not Operator here. What statement can i put here to hide the div?

Comment: I have not done web development for a long time, but don't do that using HTML/CSS. If it is sensitive information that has to be hidden from a group of users, it must not be delivered to the users browser. Use something on the server side instead.

Comment: @Alex...How do I do that? I have no idea about coding :)

Comment: That depends on what language/framework is used server side.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using PHP. When the user logs in you set a `$_SESSION` variable like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['permission'] = 'New Joinees'; //Database check when login
?>
```

then you can put into your HTML

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['permission'] == 'New Joinees'){
       echo '<div>New Joinee content here</div>';
    }elseif($_SESSION['permission'] == 'Administrator'){
       echo '<div>Administrator content here</div>';
    }
?>
```

this way you ensure that the HTML will be sent to a user that is allowed to see it only.